# How can I cheat without marking my game as modified?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

X3 games are famously filled with one-off, heavily randomized opportunities (Pandora tunings, PALCs during Shady Business, overtuned mission reward ships, etc), getting the most out of which requires both foreknowledge and a significant sacrifice of the player's sanity to hours of saving and reloading. As a typical X3 game spans hundreds of RL hours, there is significant pressure to take advantage of these opportunities. If I do not want to waste my life hoping for the RNG god to smile on me, I turn to cheats.

So far I've figured out how to give myself billions of credits (Memory editing, nuff said) and increase cargo capacity of a ship (Memory edit the amount of wares, eject the hacked wares). Are there any other cheating options that won't mark my game as modified? Some memory editing tricks I've missed, particularly for engine tunings and rudder optimizations? Perhaps the key used to sign scripts officially endorsed by Egosoft has been cracked, allowing us to cheat however we like?

Comment: @spartacus I've been memory editing for credits and cargo space in X3R, TC and AP without ever getting a modified tag. I've heard some AV software may cause your game to be flagged as modified erroneously (or at least for the wrong reasons, you rascal you), or perhaps hacking max speed is what trips it up. How did you manage to memory edit engine tunings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Unmodifier](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1atdLILlMxCPgK1C6_Hksel4siwBFgtObtaDo2fxbkJk/view?pli=1) to use any scripts and mods your save as modified. The only exception are scripts that need to be run via the script editor, however those scripts are few and far between; if need be you can manually edit the script to include a hotkey or a command console option to run it.